# "this" changes when I add parameters to event handler function

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I've started to get into javascript recently and I've hit a bit of a snag in understanding. The following may be specific to Kinetic.js, I'm unsure. Anyway, best shown with an example.
http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Eww/1/

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });
  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: stage.getWidth() / 2,
    y: stage.getHeight() / 2 + 10,
    id: "TheCircle",
    radius: 70,
    fill: 'red',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    draggable: true
  });

  var dragendHandler = function dragendHandler() {
    console.log(this);
  };
  var dragstartHandlerParams = function dragstartHandlerParams(param1) {
    console.log(this+param1);
  };

  circle.on('click', function() {
    console.log(this);
  });
  circle.on('dragend', dragendHandler);
  circle.on('dragstart', dragstartHandlerParams("ROCK"));

  layer.add(circle);
  stage.add(layer);


  document.getElementById('removeClick').addEventListener('click', function() {
    circle.off('click');
    alert('onclick removed');
  }, false);
```

Referencing the jsfiddle, I do the following:

1. Press the Run button
2. Drag the circle (triggers the dragstart and dragend)
3. Click the Circle

This results in the following console output:

```
[object Window]ROCK => Occurs after step 1.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined kinetic-v4.6.0.min.js:2 => Occurs after step 2.
Kinetic.Circle {} => Occurs after step 2.
Kinetic.Circle {} => Occurs after step 3.
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does `[object Window]ROCK` get output to the console when the the jsfiddle is initially run? The dragstart did not occur, so that should not be the reason. `dragstartHandlerParams` and `dragendHandler` are both functional expressions that are listening to drag events, so I would expect them to act the same (at this point, it doesn't seem like `dragendHandler` is executed.)
2. Why does the context of `this` change between `dragstartHandlerParams` and `dragendHandler`?
3. Why does `dragstartHandlerParams` not work as a handler? Note that it does work if I leave out the parameter when calling.
4. If the answer to question 3 is "because it is expecting an event parameter", how do I pass data to the event handler? From what I understand, the Kinetic.js `#on` function does not pass data like the jQuery `#on` function.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the following calls `dragstartHandlerParams` immediately and passes its `return` value (`undefined`, in this case) to `circle.on()`.

```
circle.on('dragstart', dragstartHandlerParams("ROCK"));
```

To specify an argument without calling the function yet, you can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
circle.on('dragstart', dragstartHandlerParams.bind(circle, "ROCK"));
```

Or, you could revise `dragstartHandlerParams` to return a new `function` to pass to `circle.on()` that has the argument [closed over](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

```
var dragstartHandlerParams = function dragstartHandlerParams(param1) {
  return function () {
    console.log(this+param1);
  };
};
```